# How can I get a filter to work in firefox with a transition?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a site animtation where I have images moving down the page using css, I want to be able to apply a blur to the images at the start and then reduce it having it completely taken away at 50%. I have it working for chrome using the webkit but I cant get the svg working for firefox or explorers version working either. The code i'm using for the svg is:

```
<svg>
    <filter id="blur_0"><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0" /></filter>
    <filter id="blur_5"><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" /></filter>
    <filter id="blur_10"><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10" /></filter>
</svg>
```

I am completely new to the use of svg's so I have no idea where im supposed to put this code like in the html or the css or a new file and dont know how to link it to the piece of css code that controls the movement of my images in my css

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have a single filter and animate the stdDeviation attribute using SMIL.

Comment: Using SVG animation for the filters might be difficult to synchronize with other CSS transitions, but it looks like your only option.  Filters are *supposed* to be an animatable property, but I can't get it to work in Firefox or Chrome.  Transitions happen immediately, no delay, and keyframe animation doesn't work at all -- Firefox just ignores the filter property within the animation, and Chrome messes everything up completely (image is black, text is invisible).  You can play around with this test pen to confirm: http://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/pen/HgKqj